Creating a VIBGYOR effect in adobe illustrator
How can I create this effect in illustrator. I just want a vector art, but cannot manage one.

I have tried creating a rectangle, then slicing it vertically into 8 to 9 more sections, adding colors to each of these, but they do not blend. What else is necessary?

It looks like a gradient.
You can use an Envelope Mesh bend on an object with a linear gradient fill in Illustrator if you make sure to check the option in the Envelope options

An example. This is just a 1 x 1 Envelope mesh.


But I cannot bend the colors like you did, they remain horizontal, not that 'arc'-ish...

@M.Riyan You need to bend the mesh handles if you want an arc.

@M.Riya see example moving the handles

It does not work. In fact, I do not have the preview button abled, it is disabled in my envelope options.

@what verison of illustrator you on?

@joojaa 24.3 it is

@M.Riyan I'm not sure if this was in older versions.  The current Illustrator version is 28.7 - so perhaps try upgrading.  It definitely works, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to do it.

You can also do this with a single path and a gradient for the stroke... This may make alterations easier.

Using a Stroke Profile, or the Width Tool, allows one to narrow one end.

